# Append option to combox without modifying data store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Is there a way to add an option to a combobox **without modifying the underlying data store** in any way? I have 2 combobox elements in my form. The only difference between the two comboboxes is that one has an additional 'All' option. For example:

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
data : [{"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"}, 
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}] 
});

//The first combobox should load the data as is from the store above
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

//There should be a second combobox here that is almost identical
//to the one above, just appending an additional option (that says "All") 
//to the top of the list
```

I'm aware that there are various ways to alter the store such as:

```
states.insert(0, [{
    abbr: 'All',
    name: 'All'
 }])
```

However, I want to achieve this without altering the store, purely adding the option to the combobox itself. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I am aware that I could make the I could set the combobox 'emptyText' configuration option to 'All', but this is not what I want. I would like to have 'All' as an actual option.

Comment: Short answer is you can't, without creating a new store.

Answer (score 1):

**Combo is a simple SELECT field of HTML. Without OPTION you cannot populate the dropdown.**

Its not possible to achieve it without adding into store. Data you see in the combo comes from store.

According to the docs :

> A combobox control with support for autocomplete, remote loading, and many other features.
>
> A ComboBox is like a combination of a traditional HTML text  field and a  field; the user is able to type freely into the field, and/or pick values from a dropdown selection list. The user can input any value by default, even if it does not appear in the selection list; to prevent free-form values and restrict them to items in the list, set forceSelection to true.
>
> The selection list's options are populated from any Ext.data.Store, including remote stores. The data items in the store are mapped to each option's displayed text and backing value via the valueField and displayField configurations, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I have already made comboboxes with "All", I hope I get it right, haven't got the source code available right now, but to create an "All" option for one of the comboboxes, in ExtJS 6 you have to do something like this:

```
var storeWithAll = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    url:
    proxy: etc.
    listeners:{
        load:function(store) {
            // Add the "All" record after every load!
            store.insert(0, [{
                abbr: 'All',
                name: 'All',
                special:true
            }]);
        }
    }
});
var storeWithoutAll = Ext.create('Ext.data.ChainedStore',{
    // ChainedStore has the same data as the source:
    source: storeWithAll,
    filters:[{
        // Filter away the "All" record
        filterFn:function(item) {return !item.get("special");}
    }]
});
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox',{
    store: storeWithAll, // Use the store with "All" record
    ...
});
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox',{
    store: storeWithoutAll, // Use the store without "All" record
    ...
});
```